# How to display 5 week Days and time only in UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone

I am working with UIDatePicker with the mode UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime. UIDatePicker is working fine with specific minimum and maximum date. But I wand little change in display mode. I need to display Only 5 days of week and time only, I don't want to display Date and Month. SO please give me some idea to perform this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

UIDatePicker does not support this. You can recreate it, however, using a UIPickerView.